# XPath: select a li element if its child matches some text

Tags: python, xpath

I need to get some information from this list

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>Code: <span>1234</span></li>
        <li>3 <span>rooms</span></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

I want to identify if //li/span has the 'rooms' text and select the number 3 from the //li.
Sometimes the list does not have the this

with the number of rooms.

I've tried to get this using that:

```
//li/child::span[contains(text(), 'rooms')]
```

but when I run the python script it returns me the None value.

Comment: _I've tried to get this using that:_ What happens? Please provide a [mcve]. That XPath is matching two more divs, and a `ul` element with the class `"characteristicas"`, neither of which are in the XML you shared.

Comment: Oh sorry, I`ve just copied the xpath that I`m using and did not realized that was with the div's and classes. But when I`ve tried this xpath that I`ve provided it returns me the None value.

Comment: I've tried to get the 3 value using the `//ul/li/child::span[contains(text(), 'rooms')]` xpath, but when I run it, It just return None value to my variable (I'm using scrapy), probably cuz the xpath is wrong on `child::span`. But I've tried `//li[./span[.="rooms"]]/text()` xpath that @E.Wiest provided it returned 3 as expected.

Comment: That's useful information, but it still isn't a **[mcve]**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the below xpath.

```
//li[span[.='rooms']]/normalize-space(text())
```

[image]

Comment: This will make sure the white-space are trimmed in your output.

Comment: It does not work. returned ValueError:

`XPath error: Invalid expression in //li[span[.='rooms']]/normalize-space(text())`

Comment: Using `.../normalize-space(text())` at the end of the expression is only allowed in XPath-2.0. In XPath-1.0 you'd have to put it like this: `normalize-space(//li[span[.='rooms']]/text())`.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your sample data, you can use :

```
//li[./span[.="rooms"]]/text()
```

Output : 3